# How to print into a pdf the results of a search on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, rotativa

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I am trying to print the filtered records between two dates to a PDF. I'm using ROTATIVA to generate the PDF, the problem is that the PDF is generated correctly but with all the records and not only with the result of the record filter by the two dates.

Code for the Controller:

```
    //this method is for put the list of the records on the view
    public ActionResult SaleList()
    {
        using (inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventoryEntitiesDBA())
        {
            return View(dc.sales.ToList());
        }
    }

    //this method is to filter the records between start and end date
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaleList(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        bool Status = false;
        if(ModelStatus.IsValid())
        {
            using(inventoryEntitiesDBA dc = new inventoryEntitiesDBA())
            {
                 var d = dc.sales.Where(x => x.sale_day >= start && x.sale_day <= end).ToList();
              
                 Status = true;

                 ViewBag.Status = Status;

                 return View(d);
            }
        } 
    }

    //this method is to generate the PDF
    public ActionResult SalesToPdf()
    {
        var report = new ActionAsPdf("SaleList");

        return report;
    }
```

I don't know exactly what to do, any suggestions are appreciated.

*UPDATE ---> `view`:

```
@if (ViewBag.Status != null && Convert.ToBoolean(ViewBag.Status))
{
    //this is for print if the method for filter
    //the dates are called
    <p align="right">
         @Html.ActionLink("Generate PDF", "SalesToPdf2")
    </p>
}
else
{
    //this is for print if the method for filter the dates are not called
    <p align="right">
         @Html.ActionLink("Generate PDF", "SalesToPdf")
    </p>
}

<center>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaleList", "Sales", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        
        <span>Start Date </span> <input type="date" name="start" />
        <span> End Date </span><input type="date" name="end" />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    }
</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the `SalesToPdf` action with no parameter which means  it will always match the unfiltered list. You can pass parameters into the `ActionAsPdf` overloads as shown in the documentation [here](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa)

In your case this would probably require some kind of separate action for the filtered list like this:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SalesToPdf(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var report = new ActionAsPdf("SaleList", new {start=startDate, end=endDate});

        return report;
    }
```

So if you have unfiltered data you'd call your existing action, and for filtered data you'd call this one.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I read the documentation and did what you said, it was helpful to know more about the library, but now it throws an error: `The parameter dictionary contains a NULL entry for the 'start' parameter of the non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' of the method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SalesToPdf2 (System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'regMVC .Controllers.SalesController '. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or it must be declared as an optional parameter."
Parameter name: parameters`

Comment: I don't know why this happens if the view shows the records filtered by dates, that is, in the variable `start` the value is not null, but in the new method to print the PDF it is...

Comment: Can you show me how you're call to the SalesToPdf2 endpoint is being made? It's likely that the start and enddates aren't being sent correctly.

Comment: Alright, so, I did two methods, one for print without the filter and other for print with it (SalesToPdf2), the way that the dates are sent is through the view.